# Retry failed writing operations without delaying other steps in Spring Batch application

Tags: spring-batch

I am maintaining a legacy application written using Spring Batch and need to tweak it to never lose data.
I have to read from various webservice (one for each step) and then write to a remote database. Things goes bad when connection with the DB drops because all itens read from webservice are discarded (can't read the same item twice), and the data is lost because can not be written.

I need to setup Spring Batch to keep already read data on one step to retry the writing operation next time the step runs. The same step can not read more data until the write operation is successfully concluded. 
When not being able to write, the step should keep the read data and pass execution to the next step, after a while, when it's time to the failed step to run again, it should not read another item, retrying the failed writing operation instead.

The batch application should runs in an infinite loop and each step should gather data from one different source. Failed writing operations should be momentarily skipped (keeping the read data) to not delay others steps but should resume from the write operation next time they are called.

I am researching in various web sources aside from official docs, but Spring Batch hasn't the most intuitive docs I have come across.

Can this be achieved? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data you need to persist in case the job fails to the Batch Step's ExecutionContext. You can restart the job again with this data:

> Step executions are represented by objects of the StepExecution class.
>   Each execution contains a reference to its corresponding step and
>   JobExecution, and transaction related data such as commit and rollback
>   count and start and end times. Additionally, each step execution will
>   contain an ExecutionContext, which contains any data a developer needs
>   persisted across batch runs, such as statistics or state information
>   needed to restart

More from: http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/domain.html#domainStepExecution

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will be ok with you, but here are my thoughts on your configuration.

Since you have two remote sources that are open to failure, let us partition the overall system with two jobs (not two steps)

**JOB A**

**Step 1**: Tasklet
Check a shared folder for files. If files exist, do not proceed to the next step. Will be more understandable when writing about JOB B

**Step 2**: Webservice to files
Read from your web service and write results to flatfiles in the shared folder. Since you would be using flatfiles for the output, you will solve your "all items read from webservice are discarded  and the data is lost because can not be written."

Use Quartz or equivalent for the scheduling of this job.

**JOB B**
Poll the shared folder for generated files and create a joblauncher with the file (file.getWhere as a jobparameter). Spring integration project may help in this polling.

**Step 1**: 
Read from the file, write them to remote db and move/delete file if writing to db is successful.

No scheduling will be needed since job launching originates from polled in files.

**Sample Execution**

Time 0: No file in the shared folder

Time 1: Read from web service and write to shared folder

Time 2: Job B file polling occurs, tries to write to db.

If successfull, the system continues to execute.

If not, when Job A tries to execute on its scheduled time, it will skip reading from web service since files still exist in the shared folder. It will skip until Job B consumes the files.

I did not want to go into implementation specifics but Spring Batch can handle all of these situations. Hope that this helps.